# Using short URLs with AddThis

Tags: 7

I am using the [AddThis](https://drupal.org/project/addthis) module on my site.  Can this be configured to use short URLs instead of the native ones?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not wedded to AddThis then the [Service Links](https://drupal.org/project/service_links) module integrates with the [Shorten URLs](https://drupal.org/project/shorten) module to provide this feature. It has the advantage of not being coupled with/crippled by the AddThis service.